# sql query for scenario with multiple duplicate columns

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where i have 3 columns state1 state2 and distance with 5 rows like

```
state1 state2 distance
TX      CA     100
CA      TX     100
OH      MI     400
MI      OH     400
```

since the distance from Tx to CA and CA to TX is same i only need one  row out of the first 2 rows
ie either TX,CA,100 or CA,TX,100 and also the 5 rows are just sample data out of a million rows .I need a query for this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table can contain one-way rows then you need to include a check that a row has no counterpart that would be excluded by the`state1 < state2`condition.

```
SELECT state1, state2, distance
FROM routes r1 
WHERE state1 < state2
    -- include rows that have no duplicate
    OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM routes r2 
        WHERE r2.state1 = r1.state2 
       AND r2.state2 = r1.state1
       )
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5f6c9/1) with an added row for MI->CA that would be eliminated without the`OR NOT EXIST`predicate.

This query doesn't care if the distances differ, so if there can be rows with the same states but different distances it will return an incorrect result. This can be fixed by including the distance in the where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select distinct
    case when state1 < state2 then state1 else state2 end as state1,
    case when state1 > state2 then state1 else state2 end as state1,
    distance
from table
```

or even this:

```
select state1,state2,distance
from table
where state1 <= state2
```